# asp.net: Is there a maximum value for MaxHttpCollectionKeys (web.config)?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I need to increase `MaxHttpCollectionKeys` very often, because I have a very big application that is sending many keys.

So I ask myself, is there a maximum value, that I do not to have to change it "every day"?

E.g. something like this

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="-1" />
</appSettings>
```

where -1 stands for "maximum".

Or do I have to put a high value in there e.g. `20000` ?

P.s.: Currently I have `8000` I need to get more.

Comment: If you have 8000+ form values being posted, you may want to start re-thinking the design of the application so it's not posting that many things at once. Multiple smaller AJAX posts, perhaps?